# How can I invert the zoom direction in macOS?

Tags: macos, scrolling, zoom, system-preferences

There is an accessibility option in System Preferences to zoom the screen. I use this by holding down ctrl then scrolling up or down on the trackpad. Scrolling up makes the image bigger; scrolling down makes the image smaller. However, this is backwards to me.

[image: The Zoom option in Accessibility in System Preferences]

Apple's natural scroll direction is inverted from Windows. In Windows scrolling controls the scrollbar; In macOS, it controls the content. This paradigm holds true in 3D games that I play. When I have scrolling set to Apple's way, scrolling up pushes my character away and scrolling down pulls my character towards me (controlling the content, rather than the viewport). So I find it odd that in a few instances such as accessibility zoom and the home screen zoom on Apple watch that scrolling works essentially how I'd expect it to work in Windows.

When I scroll up on the trackpad in macOS, I want to feel like I'm pushing the screen away from me (zooming out, not in). Is there someway I can do this, perhaps by editing something akin to the Windows registry but on macOS?

Comment: yeah macOS is reversed from convention. Take Google Maps or Miro for example